# Include a file multiple times with different macros

Tags: c, macros, include

I got a file that contains generic methods for working with arrays of different number types (the basic ideas are described in [Pseudo-generics in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522341)). The type can be specified by setting a `TYPE` macro. It looks like this (just a part of it):

`array_analyzers.c`:

```
#ifndef TYPE
#error TYPE isn't defined
#endif

#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define GET_NAME(BASE, TYPE) CONCAT(BASE, TYPE)

TYPE GET_NAME(get_minimum_, TYPE) (TYPE nums[static 1], int len){
    TYPE min = nums[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (nums[i] < min) {
            min = nums[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}

#undef CONCAT
#undef GET_NAME
#undef TYPE
```

Now, I created a header file that looks like this:

`array_analyzers.h`:

```
#ifndef TYPE
#error TYPE isn't defined
#endif

#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define GET_NAME(BASE, TYPE) CONCAT(BASE, TYPE)

TYPE GET_NAME(get_minimum_, TYPE) (TYPE nums[static 1], int len);

#undef CONCAT
#undef GET_NAME
#undef TYPE
```

Finally, I want to use this from `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPE int
#include "array_analyzers.h"
#define TYPE double
#include "array_analyzers.h"

int main(void){
  int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};
  printf("%i\n", get_minimum_int(nums, 3));
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
array_analyzers.c:2:2: error: #error TYPE isn't defined
```

What exactly is wrong here? It works when I run the preprocessor first and create separate files with the right contents, but that is just awful.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to compile `array_analysers.c` in non-C99 mode.  As the error message says.  It doesn't sound like any of the pre-processor hairiness is actually where your problem comes from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don not declare the int in the loop at the beginning of a scope, but in a for loop. If you are using gcc you can add -std=c99 compiler option to accept this code.

in this function is a standard loop that should alway be accepted. In this function int i is declared at the beginning of a scope.

```
int
ansi_c (){
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ ){

    }
}
```

and in this function is a loop that is only accepted when -std=c99 or std=gnu99
is added. This function declares the int inside a loop.

```
c99(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){

    }
}
```

Comment: That was the right answer, but now I'm facing the next bug. Updated the question.