# How to cast a void pointer at runtime in C, in a way which can be used in rest of the code?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

**This is not a 'How can a mixed data type (int, float, char, etc) be stored in an array?' question read carefully please!**
Suppose I have the following void pointer, something I don't know it's type until runtime:

```
void* data;
```

now I know I can do the following, when I know the type of `data`(e.g. `int`):

```
int typed_data = *(int*)data;
```

using a `switch case` statement I could check a variable to determine which cast to perform:

```
switch(type_id) {
    case INT:
        int typed_data = *(int*)data;
        break;
    case FLOAT:
        float typed_data = *(float*)data;
        break;
    // ...
    // etc.
}
```

But, this way I will not be able to access typed_data outside the switch block, consider the below funstion as an example; It takes two void pointers, and according to the value of `type_id`, it casts the `s` and `x` to correct data types, and then does other things with the newly defined typed data:

```
int sequential_seach(int n, void* s, void* x, type_id) {
    int location = 0;
    switch(type_id) {
        case INT:
            int *list = s;
            int element = *(int*)x;
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            float *list = s;
            float element = *(float*)x;
            break;
            // ...
            // etc.
    }

    while(location < n && list[location] != element) { // <---This will cause a compile error

        location++;
        if(location > n - 1) {
            location = -1;
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

In the above function `location` and `list` are not accessible outside the `swtich` block, even if type_id matched one of the `case` values and they were defined, they are still out of scope, outside the `switch` block, therefore when the compiler reaches the line `while` resides, it complains that `location` and `list` are not defined. But these typed variables are needed for the function. So how to solve this? should I copy paste the `while` block into every `case`? That doesn't look it's a very good solution. What if I had a longer code which needed these variables in 100 different places?

Comment: Sounds like you want a different language.

Comment: Would a `union`, work for you? You could keep a struct that was a pair of type and a union that allows you to access it as any of the possible types.

Comment: Why are you trying this? [tag:c] is not well suited for such a dynamic type system, you might want to try a different language or a different approach to solve the problem. Also, as someone already mentioned, a `union` might be a better choice. Dereferencing the pointers like that is very dangerous because you are potentially invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @TimothyMurphy: You'd still need distinct code to process each of the types in the union, and means of determining which type to use.

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need generics: the ability to define functions with compile-time type parameters.

Unfortunately, C doesn't natively have generics. Fortunately, [you can use macros as pseudo-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522430/1892179) to make the preprocessor automatically generate multiple versions of your code.

Adapted from the linked answer:

```
// sequential_search.h

/* Provide some helpers that generate a name of the form of sequential_search_T,
    unique for each type argument */

#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y    
#define SEQ_SEARCH(T) TOKENPASTE(sequential_search_, T)

/* Provide the generic type definition of your function */

int SEQ_SEARCH(TYPE) (int n, void* s, void* x) {
    int location = 0;
    TYPE* list = s;
    TYPE element = *(TYPE*)x;

    while(location < n && list[location] != element) {
        location++;
        if(location > n - 1) {
            location = -1;
        }
    }

    return location;
}
```

Instantiate it once for each type argument you intend to pass:

```
// sequential_search.c

#define TYPE int
#include "sequential_search.h"
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE float
#include "sequential_search.h"
#undef TYPE

// etc.
```

Finally, create a (statically resolvable) call spot that will switch on the type id you have (the runtime information) and then immediately dispatch to one of the generic versions:

```
int sequential_search(int n, void* s, void* x, type_id) {
    switch(type_id) {
        case INT: return sequential_search_int(n, s, x);
        case FLOAT: return sequential_search_float(n, s, x);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I get compiler errors on this line: `int SEQ_SEARCH(int n, void* s, void* x)`? I get two errors: `Expected ';' after top level declaration,` and `Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation` Also I get an error on line `int sequential_search(...)` which is `ISO C requires a named parameter before '...'`

Comment: @igaar Regarding error #1: see the edit, I had a typo in the initial definition. Regarding error #2: you're right, I didn't literally mean `...`. I meant to say "provide your actual arguments here", but `...` is valid C syntax for variadic functions. See the edit now, it should be clearer.

Comment: Now I get `use of undeclared identifier 'TYPE'` in my header file and therefor `use of undeclared identifier 'list'`

Comment: @igaar Make sure you don't `#include "sequential_search.h"` in your code, because it will cause the error you're seeing. Instead, `#include "sequential_search.c"` and let *that* include the header file. The first file needs `TYPE` already defined, and that's what the second file does.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to cast a void pointer at runtime in C.

And your code doesn't check if the cast is valid either. Doing this, you will either lose some data or risk a segmentation fault since data types aren't all the same size.

Comment: While your point is valid, the question wasn't about checking.

Comment: I feel like i do answer the question since it's not possible to do it. I just point out that his code doesn't check the type validity as an added comment.

Comment: The point where I disagree is "*risk a segmentation fault*", that's not necessarily true.

Comment: And yet you don't say "it's not possible to do it," which would actually answer the question asked.

Comment: Aaah i see. Thanks. Edited the answer.