# Can I make a C function return an arbitrary type?

Tags: c, types

I've written a function that interprets serial data (CAN) and currently returns a float. I'd like the function to include an argument wherein the user specifies a return type in a string, and the function returns a value of that type. It's just a convenience thing, to avoid having to write multiple functions that share almost all of the same code.

Comment: Yes. [This is called a template.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10950828/656243)

Comment: @Lynn: He said c not c++.

Comment: And the link says "Simulation of templates in C". So they're not really templates, which are a C++ construct. Just best to be very clear on this so there's no confusion.

Comment: @Lynn, I did not follow the link.  I will follow the link!

Comment: @Lynn.  I agree, coding functions as macros is another way to go.  I thought at first that your comment was a snark (sorry!).  Coding a function using macros would eliminate the test for type, at the expense of some complexity.  A fair trade in many instances.

Comment: @johnnycrash I saw another SO Post where they went down the macro road (I think it may even be an answer on that same question.) It's interesting -- the OP on that other question specifically said that they *didn't* want to use your `void*` approach, and asked for alternatives. I don't think it's _that_ messy.

Comment: @johnnycrash BTW - to be fair, my first comment should have included, "but c++ doesn't have these, so here's a post that discusses workarounds." Fortunately, Almo clarified. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass a void pointer to the type of data you want returned.

```
void foo(char* szType, void *pOut) {
  switch (szType[0]) {
    case 'I': *(int*)pOut = 1; break;
    case 'F': *(float*)pOut = 1; break;
  }
}
```

use like this:

```
int a;
float b;
foo("I", &a);
foo("F", &b);
```

Comment: Better answer; mine is deleted. :)

Comment: +1 Yeah.. given this paradigm vs. the simulated template approach, this is cleaner, easier and faster to code.... and easier to read.

Comment: @Lynn, but the simulated template approach would be higher performance if that was needed.

Comment: @chux: he said takes a string as a parameter.  I'd go with the char like you said or an enumeration.

Comment: Yes, now see "user specifies a return type in a string".

Answer (score 1):

johnnycrash's answer is correct, but there is another way if you want to *return* an object of a specific type (rather than use the call-with-parameter-equal to `void *` pointer). That works by returning a `malloc()`'d object of the type requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
foo (char *mytype)
{
  switch (mytype[0])
    {
    case 'I':
      {
        int *i = malloc (sizeof (int));
        *i = 1;
        return i;
      }
    case 'F':
      {
        double *d = malloc (sizeof (double));
        *d = 1.234;
        return d;
      }
    default:
      return NULL;
    }
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int *ii;
  double *dd;

  ii = foo ("I");
  printf ("Integer is %d\n", *ii);
  free (ii);

  dd = foo ("F");
  printf ("Double is %f\n", *dd);
  free (dd);
  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: ahhh nice one! There is also the internal buffer method which is not thread safe.