# How to have an array with multiple types of objects, or a function, in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Wondering if you can do something like this to store arbitrary objects in an array in C:

```
void *arr[123];
int len = 0;

void
pusharr(void *object) {
  arr[len++] = &object;
}

int
main() {
  char *foo = "foo"

  pusharr(1)
  pusharr("foo")
  pusharr(&foo)
  pusharr(foo)
  pusharr(somestruct)
  pusharr(someotherstructtype)
  pusharr(afunction)
  pusharr(anythingbasically)
  pusharr(true)
  pusharr(NULL)

  // arr[4] == somestruct, etc.
}
```

Basically I'm trying to model like the `free(void *ptr)` function and pass generic pointers to any possible object type into the function, so it can save references to them. Wondering if that's possible, and if not this way then how.

In terms of functions, it's like this...

So there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249267/can-i-make-a-c-function-return-an-arbitrary-type) which shows how to pass in a void pointer to get arbitrary types out of a function.

```
void foo(char* szType, void *pOut) {
  switch (szType[0]) {
    case 'I': *(int*)pOut = 1; break;
    case 'F': *(float*)pOut = 1; break;
  }
}

int a;
float b;
foo("I", &a);
foo("F", &b);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this but attach it to an object/struct.

```
struct mydataobject {
  void *value;
}
```

This way you could have the function at least return a type.

```
mydataobject
foo() {

}
```

In my case I want to have 2 functions, `push` and `pop` that work on arbitrary data.

```
void
mypush(mydataobject something) {
  arr[index++] = something
}

mydataobject
mypop() {
  return arr[index--]
}

mydataobject a = { "foo" }
mydataobject b = { 123 }
mydataobject c = { true }
mydataobject d = { a }
// it should work with arbitrary data.
```

Wondering if anything like this is possible.

Comment: You need to add something that indicates the type to the struct with your opaque data pointer in it.

Comment: `free` actually needs just the address, not what's in it. But that's a different story. Anyways, what you're trying to create is a dynamic tuple. You might want to have a search on SO, surely something similar will pop up.

Comment: @edmz "dynamic tuple in c" brings nothing in terms of search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Just very difficult to do correctly.

Think of scripting languages like Perl, Python or Javascript. Each of those use variables that can hold different types of values. Each of those scripting languages is written in C.

So how do they do it?

Generally they use unions and type tags. A type tag is often an integer like you're using as `szType`. Sometimes they are a pointer to a structure with data about the type. Sometimes it is a combination, because integer tags are all below 0x1000 (for example) so any number larger must be a pointer.

So design a C union that can hold data about all of your data types. Include a pointer so that extra-large types do not have to make every type huge. Then design a struct that holds a type tag and one of your unions.

Then for every function you create to manipulate these structs, check the type tags and do the correct operations for each one.

I was bored. Here is some code. Note that this is C99 so it won't compile in older versions of Visual Studio (VS 2017 worked!). I used gcc and clang to compile it. Tested with valgrind so no memory leaks. After building it with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -g -O0 type-union-test.c -o type-union-test
```

run it with

```
./type-union-test 11 bb 22333333 dd 10 a 11 b
```

And the code for type-union-test.c: (also available at https://github.com/zlynx/type-union-test )

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// log10(2^64) + 2
#define MAX_INTSTRING_LEN 21

enum VAL_types {
  VAL_UNDEFINED,
  VAL_INT32,
  VAL_STRING,
  VAL_OBJECT,
};

enum OPS_RESULT_errors {
  OPS_RESULT_OK,
  OPS_RESULT_FALSE,
  OPS_RESULT_UNIMPLEMENTED,
  OPS_RESULT_INVALID_TYPE,
  OPS_RESULT_INVALID_INTEGER,
};

struct VAL;
struct OBJECT;

union VAL_type_data {
  int32_t int32;
  char *string;
  struct OBJECT *object;
};

typedef struct OPS_RESULT {
  struct VAL *val;
  enum OPS_RESULT_errors error;
} OPS_RESULT;

typedef struct VAL_OPS {
  OPS_RESULT (*set_type)(struct VAL *, enum VAL_types);
  OPS_RESULT (*copy_from_int32)(struct VAL *, int32_t);
  OPS_RESULT (*copy_from_string)(struct VAL *, const char *);
  OPS_RESULT (*move_from_key_val)(struct VAL *, struct VAL *, struct VAL *);
  OPS_RESULT (*is_equal)(struct VAL *, struct VAL *);
  OPS_RESULT (*debug_print)(struct VAL *);
} VAL_OPS;

typedef struct VAL {
  enum VAL_types type_id;
  size_t ref_count;
  union VAL_type_data type_data;
  const VAL_OPS *ops;
  bool constant;
  bool owned_ptr;
} VAL;

typedef struct OBJECT_KV {
  VAL *key;
  VAL *val;
} OBJECT_KV;

typedef struct OBJECT {
  OBJECT_KV *array;
  size_t len;
  size_t cap;
} OBJECT;

OBJECT *OBJECT_new(void);
void OBJECT_delete(OBJECT *op);
VAL *VAL_new(void);
void VAL_delete(VAL *vp);

bool result_ok(OPS_RESULT res) { return res.error == OPS_RESULT_OK; }

const char *result_error_str(enum OPS_RESULT_errors err) {
  switch (err) {
  case OPS_RESULT_OK:
    return "OK";
  case OPS_RESULT_FALSE:
    return "false";
  case OPS_RESULT_UNIMPLEMENTED:
    return "unimplemented";
  case OPS_RESULT_INVALID_TYPE:
    return "invalid type";
  case OPS_RESULT_INVALID_INTEGER:
    return "invalid integer";
  default:
    return "unknown error";
  }
}

void result_print(OPS_RESULT res) {
  FILE *out = stdout;
  fprintf(out, "{error: \"%s\"", result_error_str(res.error));
  if (result_ok(res) && res.val) {
    res.val->ops->debug_print(res.val);
  }
  fprintf(out, "}");
}

VAL *result_unwrap(OPS_RESULT res) {
  if (res.error != OPS_RESULT_OK) {
    result_print(res);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    abort();
  }
  return res.val;
}

void *xmalloc(size_t bytes) {
  void *p = malloc(bytes);
  if (!p)
    abort();
  return p;
}

void xfree(void *p) { free(p); }

void xrealloc(void **p, size_t bytes) {
  void *new_p = realloc(*p, bytes);
  if (!new_p)
    abort();
  *p = new_p;
}

// Got to take into account the virtual functions we are not using yet!
// One val may have reimplemented is_equal so check both ways. For SCIENCE!
// And unnecessary complexity!
OPS_RESULT VAL_is_equal(VAL *v1_p, VAL *v2_p) {
  if (result_ok(v1_p->ops->is_equal(v1_p, v2_p)) &&
      result_ok(v2_p->ops->is_equal(v2_p, v1_p)))
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_FALSE};
}

OPS_RESULT VAL_default_set_type(VAL *vp, enum VAL_types type_id) {
  if (vp->type_id != VAL_UNDEFINED && vp->type_id != type_id)
    // Would need to implement type conversion.
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_UNIMPLEMENTED};
  vp->type_id = type_id;
  switch (type_id) {
  case VAL_OBJECT:
    vp->type_data.object = OBJECT_new();
    break;
  default:
    // Do nothing special.
    break;
  }
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

OPS_RESULT VAL_default_copy_from_int32(VAL *vp, int32_t source) {
  int r;
  switch (vp->type_id) {
  case VAL_INT32:
    vp->type_data.int32 = source;
    break;
  case VAL_STRING:
    if (vp->type_data.string)
      xfree(vp->type_data.string);
    vp->type_data.string = xmalloc(MAX_INTSTRING_LEN);
    r = snprintf(vp->type_data.string, MAX_INTSTRING_LEN, "%d", source);
    if (r >= MAX_INTSTRING_LEN)
      abort();
    break;
  default:
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_INVALID_TYPE};
  }
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

OPS_RESULT VAL_default_copy_from_string(VAL *vp, const char *s) {
  int r;
  char *cp;
  long lval;
  switch (vp->type_id) {
  case VAL_INT32:
    errno = 0;
    lval = strtol(s, &cp, 0);
    if (errno == ERANGE || !(*cp == '\0' || isspace(*cp)) ||
        !(lval <= INT_MAX && lval >= INT_MIN))
      return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_INVALID_INTEGER};
    vp->type_data.int32 = lval;
    break;
  case VAL_STRING:
    if (vp->type_data.string)
      xfree(vp->type_data.string);
    r = strlen(s);
    vp->type_data.string = xmalloc(r + 1);
    strcpy(vp->type_data.string, s);
    break;
  default:
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_INVALID_TYPE};
  }
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

// This is a move because it does not increment reference counts of key or val.
OPS_RESULT VAL_default_move_from_key_val(VAL *vp, VAL *key, VAL *val) {
  // Must be an OBJECT
  if (vp->type_id != VAL_OBJECT)
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_INVALID_TYPE};
  // Find existing key
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < vp->type_data.object->len; i++) {
    if (result_ok(VAL_is_equal(vp->type_data.object->array[i].key, key))) {
      // Delete existing key and value
      VAL_delete(vp->type_data.object->array[i].key);
      VAL_delete(vp->type_data.object->array[i].val);
      break;
    }
  }
  // Insert new key and value
  if (i == vp->type_data.object->len) {
    // Might have to realloc.
    if (i == vp->type_data.object->cap) {
      if (vp->type_data.object->cap > 0)
        vp->type_data.object->cap *= 2;
      else
        vp->type_data.object->cap = 4;
      xrealloc((void **)&vp->type_data.object->array,
               vp->type_data.object->cap * sizeof *vp->type_data.object->array);
    }
    vp->type_data.object->len++;
  }
  vp->type_data.object->array[i].key = key;
  vp->type_data.object->array[i].val = val;
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

OPS_RESULT VAL_default_is_equal(VAL *v1_p, VAL *v2_p) {
  // Not going to do type conversion right now.
  if (v1_p->type_id != v2_p->type_id)
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_UNIMPLEMENTED};
  switch (v1_p->type_id) {
  case VAL_INT32:
    if (v1_p->type_data.int32 != v2_p->type_data.int32)
      return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_FALSE};
    break;
  case VAL_STRING:
    if (strcmp(v1_p->type_data.string, v2_p->type_data.string) != 0)
      return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_FALSE};
    break;
  default:
    // Not going to compare OBJECTS right now. Too hard.
    return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_UNIMPLEMENTED};
  }
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

OPS_RESULT VAL_default_debug_print(VAL *vp) {
  FILE *out = stdout;
  size_t i;
  switch (vp->type_id) {
  case VAL_INT32:
    fprintf(out, "%d", vp->type_data.int32);
    break;
  case VAL_STRING:
    fprintf(out, "\"%s\"", vp->type_data.string);
    break;
  case VAL_OBJECT:
    fprintf(out, "{");
    for (i = 0; i < vp->type_data.object->len; i++) {
      if (i > 0)
        fprintf(out, ", ");
      vp->type_data.object->array[i].key->ops->debug_print(
          vp->type_data.object->array[i].key);
      fprintf(out, ": ");
      vp->type_data.object->array[i].val->ops->debug_print(
          vp->type_data.object->array[i].val);
    }
    fprintf(out, "}");
    break;
  default:
    fprintf(out, "\"undefined type\"");
    break;
  }
  return (OPS_RESULT){.error = OPS_RESULT_OK};
}

static const VAL_OPS VAL_OPS_template = {
    .set_type = VAL_default_set_type,
    .copy_from_int32 = VAL_default_copy_from_int32,
    .copy_from_string = VAL_default_copy_from_string,
    .move_from_key_val = VAL_default_move_from_key_val,
    .is_equal = VAL_default_is_equal,
    .debug_print = VAL_default_debug_print,
};

static const VAL VAL_template = {.type_id = VAL_UNDEFINED,
                                 .ref_count = 1,
                                 .type_data = {0},
                                 .ops = &VAL_OPS_template,
                                 .constant = false,
                                 .owned_ptr = false};

VAL *VAL_new(void) {
  VAL *p = xmalloc(sizeof *p);
  *p = VAL_template;
  return p;
}

void VAL_delete(VAL *vp) {
  if (--vp->ref_count == 0) {
    switch (vp->type_id) {
    case VAL_STRING:
      xfree(vp->type_data.string);
      break;
    case VAL_OBJECT:
      OBJECT_delete(vp->type_data.object);
      break;
    default:
      // Do nothing.
      break;
    }
    xfree(vp);
  }
}

static const OBJECT OBJECT_template = {0};

OBJECT *OBJECT_new(void) {
  OBJECT *p = xmalloc(sizeof *p);
  *p = OBJECT_template;
  return p;
}

void OBJECT_delete(OBJECT *op) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < op->len; i++) {
    VAL_delete(op->array[i].key);
    VAL_delete(op->array[i].val);
  }
  xfree(op->array);
  xfree(op);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  VAL *top = VAL_new();
  result_unwrap(top->ops->set_type(top, VAL_OBJECT));
  for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i += 2) {
    VAL *key = VAL_new();
    VAL *val = VAL_new();
    result_unwrap(key->ops->set_type(key, VAL_INT32));
    // key->ops->copy_from_int32(key, i);
    result_unwrap(key->ops->copy_from_string(key, argv[i]));
    result_unwrap(val->ops->set_type(val, VAL_STRING));
    // val->ops->copy_from_string(val, argv[i]);
    result_unwrap(val->ops->copy_from_string(val, argv[i + 1]));

    result_unwrap(top->ops->move_from_key_val(top, key, val));
  }

  top->ops->debug_print(top);
  printf("\n");

  VAL_delete(top);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mind demonstrating with some code? This gives me some to search on though, thank you!

Comment: @LancePollard Here's a link to some Perl documentation which can show the API and how complex it gets. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html

Answer (score 0):

### Store `union` Objects

A `union` lets you hold one of several different types.  If the first member is some kind of `enum` that declares which member of the `union` is active, that’s called a **discriminated union**.

### Store `void` Pointers

A `void*` can reference any type of object, so if the objects themselves exist outside the array, the array can hold pointers to them.  You still need some way to remember what the type of the objects was, such as a structure containing both an `enum` and a `void*`.

### Store Arrays of `char`

An array of `char` or `unsigned char` can hold the object representation of any object its size or smaller.  Make sure that the arrays are aligned to `max_align_t` to guarantee that they have the correct alignment to store any datatype, or just specify multiple types that are required to be correctly aligned.  You could cast the `char*` to the correct type of pointer.

Using a `union` handles this all for you..