# New types from old: can I get a macro to do my work for me?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I program in C, and have got into the pattern of doing as follows after defining a new type:

1. add a default value for the type, almost always called `typename_null_c`.
2. add a function which returns a pointer to a struct of my new type, filled in with the default value defined in 1; this is almost always called `typename_create()`.
3. add a function which calls existing deallocation functions on all the pointer fields in my structure; this is almost always called `typename_free(...)`, and always receives a pointer to a structure of my new type.

I do this again and again, but with different numbers of arrays, lists, hash-tables and other standard types each time. What I'd like to be able to do (but am not sure if it's possible) is to get the preprocessor to write some of this for me. In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
lazy_m( newtypename, 
     type1name, type1_default_c, type1_create, type1_free,
     type2name, type2_default_c, type2_create, type2_free,
     ...
     type100name, type100_default_c, type100_create, type100_free )
```

and end up with `newtypename_null_c`, `newtype_create()` and `newtype_free` written for me. I (naively) expect this to be possible through judicious use of the `##` directive, but haven't done enough of this kind of thing to know (a) if it's possible at all and (b) where to begin.

In case this isn't clear from above, what I'm after is how to write the `lazy_m` macro: it's the mechanism for generating new null_c, create and free functions from existing ones that I'm aiming for.

Do let me know if you'd like me to clarify anything about my question, and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**To summarise the consensus quickly reached in the comments:** yes, it can probably be done, but it's better for everyone if you don't try.

Comment: What is the significance of the arguments to your example macro call?  I understand `newtypename`, but are the others specifying details of structure members?

Comment: At that point you'd probably benefit from using C++ and structs with constructors/destructors.

Comment: In general, the end result of getting macros to do the work for you, is defining your own language but craftily implemented in C, and is then unreadable code and hard to debug. Don't be lazy. Save macros for things you can't do in plain C.

Comment: Gonna echo what @WeatherVane says here.  Yes, this is quite possible to do with macros, but I feel very sorry for the person (you) who will end up trying to debug this in the future when it goes sideways and the debugger is showing level upon level of macro hell.  I've done buggery like this for AI function pointer tables for init/loop/end and it has worked, but there is a price in debug time.  Having the functions call canned functions for most of their attributes helped - but then all I really did was half-ass re-invent inheritance in C.

Comment: I concur.  Yes, you can get the preprocessor to do what you describe.  It would be its own nasty mess consisting of a fairly large chunk of macro code, and it would make life harder on anyone trying to work with the code base, probably even you.  Consider instead writing a *code generator* to help you, so that all the needed functions and declarations can be present literally in the code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that's right yes; the other fields specify the default value, and the create/free functions for the member types.

Comment: @WeatherVane and Michael Dorgan. Yes... I don't expect it to be pretty, but thought it might be a standard time-saving mechanism; I take your point about the debug time thought. I didn't really think about how much I hate having to debug stuff like this when I asked my question.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe the would be a better place if I don't get the answer to my question... Thanks everyone!

Comment: `I program in C, ...` No you don't.

Comment: @wildplasser. No, but I try :)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950828/simulation-of-templates-in-c-for-a-queue-data-type answer your question? Generally the answer with `define_list(int)` show an example that defines the list for `int` type, just like your macro.