# key value in C with different data type

Tags: c, dictionary, struct, hashmap

I am working on c and I am trying to implement a dictionary(key, value) pair in C, but the list of keys I have are from different type e.g.(int x. double y, char z) in that cast what will be the type of key and value inside the struct?

UPDATE: the main purpose of that is to store the values of all variables in a specific program (I need to have a dictionary of var:val)

is that possible in C?

```
struct key_value
{
    char key;  // what is the type of key?
    int value; // what is the type of value?
};
```

Comment: Do you need to retain the type? If not use `sprintf()` to convert all to their textual representation and store them as C-string? Else things become complicated.

Comment: Why are the keys of such varying types? Or is it the value that is really of varying type, and the key indicates the type? What's the overall problem that this structure is intended to solve?

Comment: Do you want to keep all the data types unchanged?

Comment: @ArisKantas yes because by the I need to print all of these values and in order to print them i need to know their type.

Comment: You can use template struct. This may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950828/simulation-of-templates-in-c-for-a-queue-data-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950828/simulation-of-templates-in-c-for-a-queue-data-type)

Comment: @alk the main problem is how to implement this hashmap with many types, I also tried to store everything as a char but once I assigned an integer value to a key, I got an incompatible type error.

Comment: You probably need to pass a `void *` pointing at the key and a length identifying how many bytes of data are in the key, and similarly for the value.  Hence `struct key_value { void *key_data; size_t key_len; void *val_data; size_t val_len; };` — you might or might not decide to hash the key and store the (fixed size) hash too.

Answer (score 0):

> the main purpose of that is to store the values of all variables in a specific program

As only the user of your library is knowing what the key is and how it's stored and how to compare it, the user should pass it's own functions and callback to use the keys.

```
struct map_s {
    /* some data for the map */
    int (*key_cmp)(void *key1, void *key2); 
};

struct key_value {
    void *key;
    int value; // what is the type of value?
};
```

Or you can put the function pointer inside `struct key_value`, depending on how do you want your implementation to look like. Then your library can call user supplied compare function to know, if the key is this key or not.

```
int map_find_value(struct map_s *map, void *key) {
    for (struct key_value *iterator /* iterate over key_values here */ ) {
       if (map->key_cmp(key, iterator->key)) {
             return iterator->value;
        }
     }
}
```

If your library doesn't know what key is, you shouldn't do any assumptions about it - let the user of you library handle it then.

Depending on your library implementation, you may want also to pass a function pointer that will destruct/free the key like ex. `void (*key_destruct)(void *key)` and ex. that will copy the key, like `int (*key_copy)(void **to, void *from)`, so that you can operate on keys.