# #define structure name in C

Tags: c

Is it possible/ is there any way to write something like this in the .h file?

```
#define _struct 'profile'


int output(_struct list[],int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n"list[i].name);
    }
}
```

In the .c file, I declare the struct name (`profile` in this example) and in the header file I define the struct name like above. My aim is when another .c file use this header, I only have to change the structure name in #define.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want this.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are trying to achieve something like [**C++** templates](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) but in **C**.

Although it is not possible in **C** to achieve this kind of behavior, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950828/simulation-of-templates-in-c-for-a-queue-data-type) which is trying to accomplish something similar using macros.