# Is it possible to modularize C functions with different argument types?

Tags: c, file, b-tree, modularity

I'm building a bTree to deal with 2 different file types.

```
struct bNode {
    char nodeType;
    int numKeys;
    Key key[MAX_KEYS+1];
    int desc[MAX_DESC+1];
};

struct bNode2 {
    char nodeType;
    int numKeys;
    Key2 key[MAX_KEYS+1];
    int desc[MAX_DESC+1];
};
```

Each node has the specified struct as above.
I would like to use the same function `searchID()` on both (instead of creating `searchID2()` for example).

```
int searchID(FILE *indexFile, struct bNode *node, int id) {
    if (node->nodeType == LEAF) {
        for (int i = 0; i < node->numKeys; i++)
            if (node->key[i].id == id)
                return node->key[i].rrn;
    } else {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < node->numKeys && id > node->key[i].id)
            i++;
        if (id == node->key[i].id)
            return node->key[i].rrn;

        struct bNode *desc = readNode(indexFile, node->desc[i]);
        return searchID(indexFile, desc, id);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Tried to implemented using `void *` but it didn't work at all.

Comment: You could merge the two structs, then use a union of the two different keys, and add a tag (say, enum) to tell which type a given node is.  Then you switch on key and have a per node-type specific code.

Comment: A minimal hack would be to create a enum with a type, pass that into searchID, and change struct bNode to void *node, then use the enum type to cast the pointer to the correct type.

Comment: 3rd option, create a macro that generate the search code and pass in the type.  Then generate two versions and call the right one based on type.

Comment: See my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) for some ideas

Comment: Next time please post a self-contained code instead of a snippet [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulation of templates in C (for a queue data type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950828/simulation-of-templates-in-c-for-a-queue-data-type) The macro+include technique is what is important. It is the cleanest of two ways to get templated stuff in C.

Comment: Merging both structs with union was exactly what I was looking for, @AllanWind. Thanks

Comment: @Fróis I wrote it up as an answer if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the two structs by using an embedded `union` then using the `nodeType` as a tag to figure out which of the two keys you are interested for a given instance of the `struct`:

```
struct bNode {
    char nodeType;
    int numKeys;
    union {
       Key key[MAX_KEYS+1];
       Key2 key2[MAX_KEYS+1]; // note: renamed to key2 to not conflict
    };
    int desc[MAX_DESC+1];
};
```

Then in your function you switch on nodeType to figure out if you need to handle `key` or `key2`.  You don't tell us anything about the types Key and Key2 so I am writing psudo code here (replace ...):

````
int searchID(FILE *indexFile, struct bNode *node, int id) {
    if (node->nodeType == LEAF) {
        for (int i = 0; i < node->numKeys; i++) {
            if(nodeType == ... && node->key[i].id == id)
                    return node->key[i].rrn;
            else if(nodeType == ... && node->key2[i] ... )
                    ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
    return -1;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you were to code something like the following example, I would think that you could get by with on structure definition but utilize two node variables in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_KEYS 1000
#define MAX_DESC 1000
#define LEAF 'l'

typedef struct Kxx                                  /* Made this up for example purposes */
{
    int id;
    int rrn;
} Key;

struct bNode{                                       /* Just have one definition for the binary tree node */
    char nodeType;
    int numKeys;
    Key key[MAX_KEYS+1];
    int desc[MAX_DESC+1];
};

struct bNode * readNode(FILE *idxFile, int desc)    /* Made this up for example purposes */
{
    return NULL;
}

int searchID(FILE *indexFile, struct bNode *node, int id){
    if(node->nodeType == LEAF){
        for(int i = 0; i < node->numKeys; i++)
            if(node->key[i].id == id)
                return node->key[i].rrn;
    }else{
        int i = 0;

        while(i < node->numKeys && id > node->key[i].id)
            i++;
        if(id == node->key[i].id)
            return node->key[i].rrn;

        struct bNode *desc = readNode(indexFile, node->desc[i]);
        return searchID(indexFile, desc, id);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    struct bNode *bNode1;       /* In lieu of having two binary tree node structure definitions */
    struct bNode *bNode2;

    bNode1 = (struct bNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bNode));
    bNode2 = (struct bNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bNode));

    int result;

    FILE * file1 = fopen("tree_one.txt", "r");
    FILE * file2 = fopen("tree_two.txt", "r");

    result = searchID(file1, bNode1, 33);

    result = searchID(file2, bNode2, 759774);

    printf("Result test: %d\n", result);  /* Just printing so as to avoid an unused variable warning */

    return 0;
}
```

Please give that some consideration.  There is no duplicate of the "bNode" structure.  You could just define and allocate two node sets using "bNode".  Hope that provides some food for thought.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a template, implemented by macros. Then you will have two different types `struct bNode_Key` and `struct bNode_Key2`, and different functions to operate on each of them. Looks like you also need to template `readNode`.

```
#define TEMPLATE_bNode(T) \
struct bNode_ ## T { \
    char nodeType; \
    int numKeys; \
    T key[MAX_KEYS+1]; \
    int desc[MAX_DESC+1]; \
};

#define TEMPLATE_searchID(T) \
int searchID_ ## T(FILE *indexFile, struct bNode_ ## T *node, int id) { \
    ... \
    struct bNode_ ## T *desc = readNode_ ## T(indexFile, node->desc[i]); \
    ... \
}

#define TEMPLATE_readNode(T) \
int readNode_ ## T(FILE *indexFile, int desc) { \
    ...
}

TEMPLATE_bNode(Key1)
TEMPLATE_searchID(Key1)
TEMPLATE_readNode(Key1)

TEMPLATE_bNode(Key2)
TEMPLATE_searchID(Key2)
TEMPLATE_readNode(Key2)
```

However, if your `T` is supposed to consist of many tokens like in `unsigned int`, then the above simplified example will not work. Instead, you could distinguish between the name and the suffix like

```
#define TEMPLATE_bNode(T, SUFFIX) \
struct bNode_ ## SUFFIX { \
    ... \
    T key[MAX_KEYS+1]; \
    ...
```

and then use something like `TEMPLATE_bNode(unsigned int, unsigned_int)`, which would result in the type name `bNode_unsigned_int`.