# Using void pointers for unknown return types in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, void-pointers

I'm trying to implement a linked list and the values held by each node need not always be the same type. I've used a void pointer to store the value, but the issue I'm having is retrieving the value from the node. I want to write a single function that contains a switch statement to cast the value to the appropriate type, but I'm not sure how to handle an unknown return type other than using another void pointer.

Is there a way around this, or perhaps a more efficient way to handle unknown data types?

Comment: If it can be one of several types that you know ahead of time, try a union. And instead of having a `get()` function, make things like `getInt()`, `getString()` etc, or maybe a templated `get<T>()`. Better still, if you can use Boost, try `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.

Comment: `std::list<boost::any>` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't use `void*` unless you're a 100% sure what you're doing.
2. You don't use `T*` pointers for `value`
3. You don't use raw pointers at all, but the appropriate idioms from the [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) facilities of the c++ standard library.
4. You use the standard *linked-list* implementation: [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

> *"Is there a way around this, or perhaps a more efficient way to handle unknown data types?"*

Yes there's `boost::any` or `boost::variant` as mentioned, though these aren't c++ standard types.

Comment: I would add, never use a linked list (std::list) unless you know that's what you really need. Use std::vector by default, unless you know you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

If the pointers you are storing are all to classes that you've created, can you create a common base class?  Then you simply have a linked-list of pointers to the base class type.

When you need to retrieve a derived pointer from a base class pointer, you can try a series of `if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClass>(ptr) != nullptr)` tests until one of them passes -- then you know you've hit the right type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even if the function is inside another module rather than the client function. I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039513/type-safe-generic-data-structures-in-plain-old-c/31654151#31654151). But one possible problem with void pointers is the fact that you have to keep track of all types, verifying each one of them with switch statement as you said.I've shared a huge peice of code that kind of does the job. Hope you like it!