# Void pointers, type casting and possible code improvements

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

Considering the code as follows:

```
void get_value_by_peek_name(json_object *json_obj, const char *peak_name, void **value) {
    json_object *value_obj;
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(json_obj, peak_name, &value_obj))
        if (json_object_is_type(value_obj, json_type_double))
            sscanf(json_object_to_json_string(value_obj), "%lf", *value);
}
```

This implementation, as expected, generates a warning:

```
format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 3 has type ‘void *’
```

I am looking for a suggestion to better implement this function and, of course, avoid the warning above.

Elsewhere, considering also the code:

```
double timestamp;
void *holder;

// some other code...
// response_obj already initialized 
get_value_by_peek_name(response_obj, "timestamp", &holder);
timestamp = *((double *) holder);
printf("- timestamp: %lf\n", timestamp);
```

Is there a good way to make this code *more elegant*, without declaring explicitly the **void pointer** `holder` but by using directly `timestamp` to hold the value?

Comment: In the line `sscanf(json_object_to_json_string(value_obj), "%lf", *value);`, change to `(double *)*value`, and make sure you have `void *holder = &timestamp;`, and get rid of the line `timestamp = *((double *) holder)`

Comment: `holder` is not initialized.

Comment: If `holder` is not initialized then you are passing an uninitailized pointer to sscanf

Comment: Yes, but the `sscanf` writes correctly the value.

Comment: No it doesn't . You possibly mean it *appears* to write the value when you ran the code, but in fact you are seeing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Weird. I have tested the code above and it works correctly.

Comment: Testing is no guarantee that your code is correct. Try `char *p = malloc(3);  p[4] = 'x';`  and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Which one is the right way to initialize it? I am currently just using `holder` as temp variable to pass as argument to the function `get_value_by_peek`, even if would be better avoid to use it (the second point of the question).

Comment: See my comment above with the code in it .  If you want to avoid the temp variable you will have to change the function definition, as shown in alk's example.

Comment: It works and made my mind more clear. Thanks ;)

Comment: Check this [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039513/type-safe-generic-data-structures-in-plain-old-c/31654151#31654151)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> avoid the warning above.

1. Define `get_value_by_peek_name()` to take a `void*` as last parameter:

   ```
   void get_value_by_peek_name(json_object * json_obj, const char * peak_name, void * value)
   ```
2. Make sure `holder` points to a `double` (or at least to enough memory, which as well is properly aligned to hold a `double`), then
3. properly cast the pointer in the call to `sscanf()` *before* dereferencing it:

   ```
   sscanf(json_object_to_json_string(value_obj), "%lf", *((double**)value));
   ```

Comment: wouldn't the cast `(double *)value` be enough (assuming you call `get_value_by_peek_name( ....., &timestamp );`) ?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt that would be one approach, alk is suggesting a different approach

Comment: No, as `value` had been initilalised on call as `&holder`. This applies to the way the OP calls `get_value_by_peek_name()`.